# Simplify this code

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I hate code that looks like its been hacked together.  I have just written this:

```
update table1.dbo.totals
    set @FEE = case
       when isnull(g.SGROUPS,0) > 1
         then @GROUPPRICE * case
             when CHARINDEX('JMCG', g.GROUPS) > 0
                 then (g.SGROUPS - 2)
                 else (g.SGROUPS - 1)
                 end
             else      0
          end   
from @GROUPMEM as g

if @FEE < 0
begin
    set @GROUPFEE = 0
end
```

I'm particularly wanting to get rid of that nested CASE.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Does this code actually work anyway? What does `update table1.dbo.totals set @FEE = ...` do?

Comment: Yea it does work.  It basically checking if a certain value is present (JMCG), and multiply by g.SGROUPS - 2 or g.SGROUPS - 1 depending on it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so this a little odd but may be cool.  It gets rid of your nested case and uses some [bitwise operations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176122.aspx)...

```
update table1.dbo.totals
    set @FEE = COALESCE((g.SGROUPS^1)&1,0) * @GROUPPRICE * 
          case
             when CHARINDEX('JMCG', g.GROUPS) > 0 then (g.SGROUPS - 2)
             else (g.SGROUPS - 1)
          end
from @GROUPMEM as g

if @FEE < 0
begin
    set @GROUPFEE = 0
end
```

You're probably asking what `(g.SGROUPS^1)&1` does...  This basically converts g.SGROUPS to one if it has a value, allowing us to use it in the multiplication.

Comment: I'm liking your thinking, but does this really simplify things?

Comment: I would say yes.  You stated that your main concern was getting rid of the nested case statements which this does...

Comment: It's somewhat hacky, but the only "simpler" answer that's available. +1 from me

Comment: Looks like this is the simplest it can get.  Bit of a shame really, I thought there would be a more 'elegant' way.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I'm going to play some math games here and take advantage of the fact that y*(x-1)-y = y*(x-2).

**EDIT**: Realized I had my (SGROUPS-1) vs. (SGROUPS-2) logic backwards and fixed.

```
update table1.dbo.totals
    set @FEE = @GROUPPRICE * isnull(g.SGROUPS-1,0) - case when isnull(CHARINDEX('JMCG', g.GROUPS),0)>0 then g.SGROUPS else 0 end
from @GROUPMEM as g

if @FEE < 0
begin
    set @GROUPFEE = 0
end
```

Answer (score 1):

For no CASE statements at all, try:

```
update table1.dbo.totals
set @FEE = @GROUPPRICE * isnull(nullif(sign(g.SGROUPS-1),-1),0)
               * (isnull(g.SGROUPS,0) - 1 - sign(CHARINDEX('JMCG', g.GROUPS))
from @GROUPMEM as g

if @FEE < 0
begin
    set @GROUPFEE = 0
end
```